# MongoDB Maximum Connection accept

Tags: php, mongodb

What is the maximum number of connections that a MongoDB can accept?

Do we need to close the connection after every request has completed successfully?

**PHP:**

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
$db = $connection->selectDB('demo');

$connection->close(); /* DO WE NEED TO CLOSE THE CONNECTION */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the maximum number of connections that a MongoDB can accept?

A lot. It depends on your operating system's ulimit setting but it's generally in the tens of thousands, and having thousands of connections at once is common for large deployments.

> Do we need to close the connection after every request has completed successfully?

Nope. Generally you should create one `MongoClient` and reuse it throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of connection pooling which will handle connections for you. No idea on to do it with PHP though.

The amount of connections is limited by memory and how many threads MongoDB can create - there is no set value.